# Vbscript add XML node after specific node

Tags: xml, vbscript

I've got the following XML

```
<list name="Model">

  <list name="Info">
   <item name="ViewName">Page</item>
   <item name="DBField">Number</item>
   <item name="Type">int</item>
  </list>

  <list name="Info">
   <item name="ViewName">Page</item>
   <item name="DBField">Text</item>
   <item name="Type">String</item>
  </list>

  <list name="Codes">
  </list>

</list>
```

I want to add a New Child `<list name="Info">` to `<list name="Model">`,
the Child has to be inserted after the Last `<list name="Info">` but before the `<list name="Codes">`part.

I've selected the last Info Node but can't figure out how to insert a node before the Codes node..

Comment: could you post your last workout

Comment: `Set newNode = xmlDoc.createElement("list")
newNode.setAttribute "name","Info"
 Set child1 = xmlDoc.createElement("item")
 Set child2 = xmlDoc.createElement("item")
 Set child3 = xmlDoc.createElement("item")
 child1.setAttribute "name","ViewName"
 child1.text = "Page"
 newNode.appendChild(child1)
 child2.setAttribute "name","DBField"
 child2.text = "Number2"
 newNode.appendChild(child2)
 child3.setAttribute "name","Type"
 child3.text = "int"
 newNode.appendChild(child3)
Set oSingleNode = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("(/list[@name='Model']/list[@name='Info'])[last()]")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.insertBefore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as in:

```
Option Explicit

Dim oXML : Set oXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
oXML.async =  False
oXML.Load "..\data\32180204.xml"

If 0 = oXML.ParseError Then
   Dim sXPath  : sXPath      = "/list/list[@name='Codes']"
   Dim ndCodes : Set ndCodes = oXML.selectSingleNode(sXPath)
   If ndCodes Is Nothing Then
      WScript.Echo sXPath, "not found"
   Else
      Dim ndNew : Set ndNew = oXML.createElement("list")
      ndCodes.parentNode.insertBefore ndNew, ndCodes
      WScript.Echo oXML.xml
   End If
Else
   WScript.Echo oXML.ParseError.Reason
End If
```

output:

```
cscript 32180204.vbs
<list name="Model">
        <list name="Info">
                <item name="ViewName">Page</item>
                <item name="DBField">Number</item>
                <item name="Type">int</item>
        </list>
        <list name="Info">
                <item name="ViewName">Page</item>
                <item name="DBField">Text</item>
                <item name="Type">String</item>
        </list>
        <list/><list name="Codes">
        </list>
</list>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what i needed :)